# PowerBI sheduled refresh

Tags: azure, powerbi

I have a powerBI which I would like to refresh. 
The refresh should be done when the datasets are up to date. 
There is no fixed time when all the datasets are up to date. they are all ready between 6h30 and 7h30.

Imho a pushed refresh is the best solution. I tried two ways of working:
- through rest API
- placing a blob on azure storage website
Both are very hard to configure in azure portal and we fail each time on security.
We do not have the authority to perform certain actions when configuring in azure, also our admins in our company do not want to grant the rights because of security reasons.

I was think of sheduling the powerBI each 15 minutes between 7 and 9am, but letting it fail when the datasets are not ready.
Does any one have any ideas how to accomplish this?

Any other suggestion is appreciated!

Thanks for your insights,

Wouter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mean time I found this:  https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/refresh-your-power-bi-dataset-using-microsoft-flow/

Through Microsoft flow there are various possibilities to automate the refresh. 
The setup is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming when referring to Power BI refresh you mean [this](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-data-refresh-apis-in-the-power-bi-service/)  If so have you looked at having your refresh trigger a Logic App or having a Logic App periodically check the status of your refresh?  If it is refresh execute the Logic App to refresh your Data set via calling the Power BI Refresh API.

Comment: I tried calling the powerBI API, but I got overruled by our admins. They have some security issues, because certain authority has to be granted which, according to them, might involve opening access to pblic

Comment: If using the API isn't an option then may have to look at [scheduling the refresh in the Power BI workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-scheduled-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

If your data is already prepared and there is no need to do modelling, you can opt to use **Direct Query** instead of **Import** mode. It reduces you usage capacity plus there is no need to set scheduled refresh as you report or dashboard will automatically update whenever your data from data source is changed.